# Load a model as DPRQuestionEncoder in HuggingFace

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I would like to load the BERT's weights (or whatever transformer) into a [DPRQuestionEncoder](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/dpr.html#transformers.DPRQuestionEncoder) architecture, such that I can use the HuggingFace *save_pretrained* method and plug the saved model into the [RAG architecture to do end-to-end fine-tuning](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/research_projects/rag).

```
from transformers import DPRQuestionEncoder
model = DPRQuestionEncoder.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

But I got the following error

```
You are using a model of type bert to instantiate a model of type dpr. This is not supported for all configurations of models and can yield errors.

NotImplementedErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-1f1b990b906b> in <module>
----> 1 model = DPRQuestionEncoder.from_pretrained(model_name)
      2 # https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/41cd52a768a222a13da0c6aaae877a92fc6c783c/src/transformers/models/dpr/modeling_dpr.py#L520

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   1211                     )
   1212 
-> 1213             model, missing_keys, unexpected_keys, error_msgs = cls._load_state_dict_into_model(
   1214                 model, state_dict, pretrained_model_name_or_path, _fast_init=_fast_init
   1215             )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in _load_state_dict_into_model(cls, model, state_dict, pretrained_model_name_or_path, _fast_init)
   1286             )
   1287             for module in unintialized_modules:
-> 1288                 model._init_weights(module)
   1289 
   1290         # copy state_dict so _load_from_state_dict can modify it

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in _init_weights(self, module)
    515         Initialize the weights. This method should be overridden by derived class.
    516         """
--> 517         raise NotImplementedError(f"Make sure `_init_weigths` is implemented for {self.__class__}")
    518 
    519     def tie_weights(self):

NotImplementedError: Make sure `_init_weigths` is implemented for <class 'transformers.models.dpr.modeling_dpr.DPRQuestionEncoder'>
```

I am using the last version of Transformers.

Comment: I think the fastest way to achieve that is to write your own class that inherits from `DPRQuestionEncoder`.

Comment: Does it make sense to do this thing (i.e. load BERT's weights inside DPRQuestionEncoder)? Or is there a way to substitute the DPR's BERT model with my BERT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, `DPRQuestionEncoder` does currently not provide any functionality to load other models. I still recommend creating your own class that inherits from `DPRQuestionEncoder` that loads your custom model and adjusts its method.

But you asked in the comments if there is another way, and yes there is in case the parameters of your model and the model that your `DPRQuestionEncoder` object is holding are **completely the same**. Please have a look at the commented example below:

```py
from transformers import BertModel

# here I am just loading a bert model that represents your model
ordinary_bert = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
ordinary_bert.save_pretrained("this_is_a_bert")

import torch
from transformers import DPRQuestionEncoder

# now we load the state dict (i.e. weights and bias) of your model
ordinary_bert_state_dict = torch.load('this_is_a_bert/pytorch_model.bin')

# here we create a DPRQuestionEncoder object 
# the facebook/dpr-question_encoder-single-nq-base has the same parameters as bert-base-uncased
# You can compare the respective configs or model.parameters to be sure 
model = DPRQuestionEncoder.from_pretrained('facebook/dpr-question_encoder-single-nq-base')

# we need to create the same keys (i.e. layer names) as your target model facebook/dpr-question_encoder-single-nq-base
ordinary_bert_state_dict = {f"question_encoder.bert_model.{k}":v for k,v in ordinary_bert_state_dict.items()}

# now we can load the bert-base-uncased weights into your DPRQuestionEncoder object 
model.load_state_dict(ordinary_bert_state_dict)
```

It works from a technical perspective but I can not tell you how it will perform for your task.